# How can I make a query depending on a value found in the table itself laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For example in my parts table I have a column 'data_source', if the value is 'db_1' then execute the first query, but if the value is 'db_2' then execute the second query

It is important to emphasize that the value which would work as a conditional is the value of the column

I hope you can help me, I've been dealing with this for a couple of days.

```
$query = self::search($search); //search from meilisearch
$query->query(function ($query) use ($parameters) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($parameters) {
        $query->where('data_source', 'db_1')->where(function ($query) use ($parameters) {});
        $query->where('data_source', 'db_2')->where(function ($query) use ($parameters) {});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a column name as string, it will be checked in the database as a string. Instead use [raw methods](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-methods):

```php
$query = self::search($search)
    ->query(
        fn ($q) => $q->whereRaw(
            'CASE data_source WHEN ? THEN condition1 WHEN ? THEN condition2 ELSE TRUE END',
            ['db_1', 'db_2']
        )
    );
```

It wasn't clear if the `db_1` and `db_2` values were user-provided values, so I parameterized them. If they're fixed strings they can safely be put directly into the query. Whatever you plan to do with `$parameters`, ensure that it is properly used as well. Raw queries can be dangerous if not used correctly.